# Почему не работает namespace?

Tags: php, ооп, namespace

Есть файл index.php с содержимым:

```
use mvc\application\lib\dev;

spl_autoload_register(
  function ($class)
  {
    $path = str_replace('\\', '/', $class . '.php');
    if (file_exists($path))
    {
    require $path;
    }
  }
);




$twist = 'ddd';
debug($twist);
?>
```

И есть файл dev.php с содержимым:

```
<?php
namespace mvc\application\lib;
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function debug($str)
{
  echo '<pre>';
  var_dump($str);
  exit;
}
?>
```

Проблема в том, что не отрабатывает namespace. В чем может быть проблема?

Ошибка apache

```
[Sun Jan 13 11:16:12.953832 2019] [:error] [pid 16293] [client 192.168.88.170:65441] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function debug() in /var/www/html/index.php:21\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 21
```

Comment: var_dump($path) посмотри

Comment: Версия php какая?

Comment: по моему namespace работает только с классами, исправьте ссылкой если не прав

Comment: @AntonKucenko http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.basics.php первые же примеры про функции =)
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.rationale.php Вот тут сразу описано что именно разделяют пространства имен: Пространства имен PHP предоставляют возможность группировать логически связанные **классы, интерфейсы, функции и константы**.

Comment: Интересная особенность. Если подключить просто через require, то всё работает как надо.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Нет никаких автолоадеров для функций. Вопрос для изучения - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737199/autoloader-for-functions